# How to set the same layout for iPad and iPad Pro?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: so far I have entered the following media query at responsive websites for the tablet portrait format:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
{...}
}
```

This allows you to control your own design for the iPad in portrait format. So far so good. If you now look at the iPad Pro (e.g. the new 10.5"), the iPad Pro is not delivered with the above design but with a media query for the desktop version.

How do I have to write the condition so that all iPads, no matter in which resolution in portrait format, always display the same design? I would only need a tip on how to expand it for the 10.5".

I tried unsuccessfully with the following code:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1400px) and (max-device-width: 1800px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.5) {
...
}
```

But that doesn't work - no matter which min-device and max-device I use.

What am I doing wrong?

Addendum: the ipad pro has a resolution of 1668 x 2224 px

Comment: Please have a look (Tablets > iPads): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: wow! Yes, now iPad Pro 10,5 shows the same layout! Great! But: not for the simple iPad. The correct code is: @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1112px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

Answer (score 0):

Try this for iPad pro

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1366px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`min-device-pixel-ratio` needs a `-webkit` prefix in iOS Safari.

You should structure your CSS rules like this

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 768px) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    // . . .
}
```

Read http://stephen.io/mediaqueries to understand more about all iOS device and orientation specific media queries.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it is quite confusing where to answer / add my question...

Thank you everybody for the help.

I found the solution here > [enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). But I had to correct the code for the simple iPad.
So the correct code is:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1112px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
}
```

This works for me. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

...no this is not correct!
The correct answer is here > http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ > "Thanks to Apple's work in creating a consistent experience for users, and easy time for developers, all 5 different iPads (iPads 1-5 and iPad mini) can be targeted with just one CSS media query. The next few lines of code should work perfect for a responsive design."
So, if you want to use the EXCACT SAME layout for ipad portrait and ipad retina portrait etc. (that is what I wanted and what I asked for) the correct code is:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
```

And if you want to have the EXACT SAME layout for ipad landscape and ipad retina landscape etc. the correct code is:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
```

You don't have to put some ratio info unless you want to have another layout for retina displays.

I hope that this information helps other people.

Thank you all for your help! Stackoverflow is the best coding help forum!